# Delete duplicate data except two

Tags: mysql

How delete duplicate data except two row?

[image: example]

id 4 must deleted, because 'mangga' already have 3 row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit painful in MySQL.  The following identifies the rows to be deleted:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = nama, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := nama, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by nama, id
     ) t
where rn > 2;
```

You can then do the delete using a join:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select t.*,
                 (@rn := if(@n = nama, @rn + 1,
                            if(@n := nama, 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as rn
          from t cross join
               (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
          order by nama, id
         ) tt
         on t.id = tt.id
    where tt.rn > 2;
```